# How to produce Fe(OH)2?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I'm interested in producing Ferrum hydroxide (II), I did some research on the internet and made a plan for myself:

1. Conduct electrolysis:
   Conduct electrolysis producing $\ce{NaOH}$ and chlorine solution.
2. Produce $\ce{HCl}$:
   Produce $\ce{HCl}$ from chlorine solution by exposing it to UV light.
3. Make iron and hydrochloric acid react:
   Adding iron in hydrochloric acid makes this reaction: $\ce{2HCl + Fe -> FeCl2 + H2}$ producing a solution with $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{FeCl2}$, then evaporate it and be left with solid $\ce{FeCl2}$ crystals.
4. Produce $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$:
   As we have $\ce{FeCl2}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$, we can make this reaction: $\ce{2NaOH + FeCl2 -> Fe(OH)2 + 2NaCl}$ producing a participate ($\ce{Fe(OH)2}$).

The information above was taken from internet, and I am not sure that it will work, I asked a question about electrolysis before and I got an answer that when conducting electrolysis of saltwater it generates $\ce{OH-}$ ions that create different chlorine-based substances, maybe they are good for making $\ce{HCl}$ acid as shown in step 2 but I'm not sure.
If this won't work, maybe there is another way of producing Ferrum hydroxide (II), if yes, then please write it in an answer. I also think that I could use baking soda as a electrolyte, but doesn't that mean that it will be same as with salt? Could there be electrolytes that don't react with chlorine? Or is there any way of producing "pure" $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{FeCl2}$?

Comment: How about using vinegar and NaOH that can be bought in a shop, which could, well, maybe even *work*?

Comment: This might sound like a frivolous  question, but *why* do you want to make Fe-(II) hydroxide? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem in the synthesis of $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$ is not the procedure to use. The main problem is how to prevent $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$ from air oxidation. Whatever the technique used, the synthesis of $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$ will be done in contact with atmospheric air. And this contact oxidizes quickly $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$ which is green, into a ferric oxide, which is brown. So it is difficult to synthesise pure green $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$, whatever the reaction to be used.

In my opinion, the best way is to dissolve maybe $1$ mole commercial $\ce{FeSO4·7H2O}$ in $1-2$ liter water (depending on the temperature), and add $2$ moles of $\ce{NaOH}$ dissolved in the minimum volume of water, filtrate the green precipitate, wash and dry it as quickly as possible, if possible in a nitrogen atmosphere. Traces of air oxidation are easy to discover by observing brown spots on the green powder.